# Is there a way to recover XAP from the windows phone device

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have been developing a WP 7.5 application and yesterday my hdd was died.
The last version is installed to the WP device but I don't sure that I can recover it from the device.
Is it posible to recover xap from the WP device?

Comment: What good would it do for you if you only have the final build not the source?

Comment: Searched a little and found out that it is possible to copy the "Folder". http://advancedexplorerwp7.codeplex.com/ Should be the way to go. Described here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=934575
I didnt test it, so on your own risk

Comment: @GnrlKnowledge I don't know, but I'll try to recover all that posible.

Comment: Unfortunatly Advenced explorer doesn't work on the WP 7.5

Comment: A good practice is to use a Source Control System. There are many free private ones out there. So you always have a Backup. I know its too late for this project but it will help you in the future

Comment: I had a local one it was died too.

Comment: Windows Phone Power Tools may be useful (http://wptools.codeplex.com/) but I don't know offhand if it'll let you get the whole XAP or just individual files.

Comment: So, I haven't found a solution and start working on the my project from the begining.